# Good references on Heston Model?

Tags: volatility, reference-request, heston, models, stochastic

I am looking for good bibliographic references on Heston Model and Stochastic volatility models in general.

Does anyone know any good introductory/intermediate references on this topic?

Comment: The book by Rouah had good coverage of the model and its extensions, including references https://www.amazon.com/Heston-Model-Extensions-Matlab-Website/dp/1118548256 when it came out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best book about Heston model and globally speaking volatility modeling is the "Stochastic Volatility Modeling" by Lorenzo Bergomi. Website : https://www.lorenzobergomi.com/
Contents : https://docs.wixstatic.com/ugd/c4ff5c_567696475b2343778b36c3725a1ad8ff.pdf

Chapter 6 is about Heston model.